# Looking for information on a particular loss function

Tags: loss-functions

I am looking for the name of a particular loss function or information about it. It is like a common loss function but slightly different.

The $\tau$ quantile of a distribution can be found by finding the value $q$ that minimizes the loss function

$$
L_1(q)=(\tau-1)\int_{-\infty}^{q}(y-q)dF_{Y}(y)+\tau\int_{q}^{\infty}(y-q)dF_{Y}(y)
$$

Is there a name for the value $q$ that minimizes the loss function

$$
L_2(q)=(1-\tau)\int_{-\infty}^{q}(y-q)^2dF_{Y}(y)+\tau\int_{q}^{\infty}(y-q)^2dF_{Y}(y)
$$

I can't seem to find this online.

Side Note: The $(\tau -1)$ changes to $(1-\tau)$ because the integrand is always negative in $L_1$ and always positive in $L_2$ so they actually are both $(1-\tau)$.